Retry delay on Function with Azure ServiceBus queue trigger
I have an Azure Function that is triggered by a Service Bus queue. When the function fails, it is retried immediately (after 1s each) up to 10x. However, I would like to retry it every five minutes. Even after reading the docs, it was not clear to me how this is supposed to be implemented.
[Function("Foo")]
public async Task Run(
  ServiceBusTrigger("FooQueue",
  Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
  Foo foo,
  int deliveryCount,
  DateTime enqueuedTimeUtc,
  string messageId)

The docs say that the retry behavior can be configured in the host.json. However it also says The clientRetryOptions settings only apply to interactions with the Service Bus service. They don't affect retries of function executions.
At the same time, I did not find a setting in the service bus queue with which the retry behavior can be configured.
What is the "official" way of implementing a retry strategy? Is it supposed to be implemented in the function itself, using delays like Task.Delay along with the DeliveryCount parameter?

As you've already found out, Service Bus trigger can only perform immediate retries by leveraging MaxDeliveryCount. Delayed retries are not supported neither by the Functions SDK nor the Azure Service Bus.
For delayed retries with Isolated Worker SDK functions, you could implement a custom solution enabled by the middleware option the new Functions SDK supports. I captured the idea in a blog post. The TLDR version is to leverage delivery count for immediate retries and issue a cloned message for delayed retries, using message headers to keep a track of the retry attempt.

Hey, thanks for your answer. I read your blog post. To break it down:

You are creating your custom error queue instead of the built-in dead letter queue because in this way, you can store the actual error (exception).
You implement the delayed retry using ScheduleMessageAsync

By the way: In your blog post it would be helpful if you included the missing extension methods CloneForError and CreateSenderFor. Other than that, great post, thanks again for your help.

What would be the drawback if I just added a Task.Delay(TimeoutAfterError) in the Catcb-Block of the function itself? I know I would still have the problem with the generic errors in the DLQ, but for the sole purpose of implementing a delay it would suffice, right?

The delay approach is prone to the problem of running out of time you have the lock, leading to message re-delivery. Let's say a queue is set up for 1 min lock. Your function took 35 seconds to process the message but failed, and your delayed retry is set to execute after 15 seconds. It looks OK, but it's not. A message lock is for 60 seconds, of which 50 seconds were already used up, and when the attempt to process after the delay is executed, the message will get unlocked and be processed by another instance. You could go up to 5 minutes lock, but it will catch up with you.

Another constraint to keep in mind is the Function's execution time. If you're on a consumption plan, there's a hard stop. A single delayed retry might not work for all scenarios, so you might want to back off more than once and not use a linear time but rather exponential. Once you go through various scenarios, the Task.Delay() approach, while valid for a specific scenario, becomes unsustainable in many other scenarios.

Ahh yes, makes sense. Thanks a lot for your explanation.
